# SQL Create table missing parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I am running these two commands to create new tables, but the second create table command keeps giving me error.

```
CREATE TABLE TEAMSTADIUM(
stadium_name varchar2(40) not null,
stadium_max_capcity number(10) not null,
stadium_field_serface varchar2(40) not null,
stadium_year_built number(4) not null,
stadium_location varchar2(40) not null,
Primary KEY(stadium_name)
)


CREATE TABLE TEAMINFO(
team_name varchar2(40) not null,
team_owner varchar2(40) not null,
team_coach varchar2(40) not null,
team_created Date() not null,
PRIMARY KEY(team_name)
foreign key(stadium_name) references TEAMSTADIUM(stadium_name)
)
```

Comment: If that's not your issue, please post your error message (which you should always do anyway)

Comment: I ran the first create table command and then the second one i am getting - ora-00907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TEAMINFO` table references `TEAMSTADIUM.stadium_name`, but has no such column of its own. Add it, and ensure it has exactly the same data type as the parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEAMINFO(
  team_name varchar2(40) not null,
  team_owner varchar2(40) not null,
  team_coach varchar2(40) not null,
  team_created Date not null,
  -- Remove ()    ^^
  -- This column must exist in both tables
  stadium_name varchar2(40) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(team_name),
  -- missing comma     ^^
  foreign key(stadium_name) references TEAMSTADIUM(stadium_name)
)
```

After applying the three modifications above, it will execute correctly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/883a4

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Date not null;` and put `;` after each `)` of end table

```
CREATE TABLE TEAMINFO(
   stadium_name varchar2(40) not null,
   team_name varchar2(40) not null,
   team_owner varchar2(40) not null,
   team_coach varchar2(40) not null,
   team_created Date not null,
   PRIMARY KEY(team_name),
   foreign key(stadium_name) references TEAMSTADIUM(stadium_name)
);
```

Comment: tried it and still no luck.

Comment: @user1817081 See this line `foreign key(stadium_name) references TEAMSTADIUM(stadium_name)` the cuote is missing in te end line and the fiel stadium_name not exist in the table `TEAMINFO` see the answer again